# Public bus from Oruro to Sajama National Park

Tags: public-transport, south-america, bolivia

I'm planning to go from Oruro to Sajama NP. The best option is to take a bus from Oruro to Arica and ask the driver to drop me off in Chungara-Tambo Quemado at Bolivia-Chile border(Bolivia side), then catch a local bus onwards to Sajama NP.

I wonder the possibility of doing so.